# How to add _token csrf globally on Laravel Inertia?

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

I have a project with Laravel Inertia and Vue Js. These day i have a problem with csrf token. I have already read the documentation here https://inertiajs.com/csrf-protection, so maybe i should add csrf token on every inertia request/response.

My question is, how to add this _token globally? So i dont need to one by one add token into my vue file, because its too much file.

My current script code on login.vue:

```
props: {
        errors: Object,
        session: Object,
        auth: Array
    },

    //define composition API
    setup(props) {
        //define form state
        const form = reactive({
            email: '',
            password: '',
        });

        //submit method
        const submit = () => {

            //send data to server
            Inertia.post('/login', {

                //data
                email: form.email,
                password: form.password,
                _token: props.auth.csrf
            });
        }
```

My HandleInertiaRequest (middleware):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Middleware;

class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The root template that's loaded on the first page visit.
     *
     * @see https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup#root-template
     * @var string
     */
    protected $rootView = 'app';

    /**
     * Determines the current asset version.
     *
     * @see https://inertiajs.com/asset-versioning
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function version(Request $request): ?string
    {
        return parent::version($request);
    }

    /**
     * Defines the props that are shared by default.
     *
     * @see https://inertiajs.com/shared-data
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function share(Request $request): array
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            //session
            'session' => [
                'status'    => fn () => $request->session()->get('status'),
                'success'   => fn () => $request->session()->get('success'),
                'error'     => fn () => $request->session()->get('error'),
            ],
            //user authenticated
            'auth' => [
                'user'          => $request->user() ?   $request->user() : null,
                'permissions'   => $request->user() ? $request->user()->getPermissionArray() : [],
                'csrf' => $request->session()->token()
            ],
            //route
            'route' => function () use ($request) {
                return [
                    'params' => $request->route()->parameters(),
                    'query' => $request->all(),
                ];
            },
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Inertia automatically adds the CSFR token in every POST request. With Laravel it's done underneath by Axios. Try to delete cache

Comment: You can add `<meta name="csrf_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />` in app.blade.php

Comment: thank you, because i cant do POST if there is no _token, it will be 419 error page expired sir

Comment: add ```<meta name="csrf_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />``` its still not globally sir

Comment: Are you checking your session domain on .env file ? try to add like this `SESSION_DOMAIN=domain.com
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false` .. and I'm miss :')

Comment: yes i have that env config sir, but its not efffect. I dont know, because the shared hosting have HSTS, and my laravel inertia vue not work good with HSTS

Comment: you can add config globaly to requests in bootstrap.js file like this `window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';` but I don't know what header you must add and what is the value , but this is the way to add config globaly

Comment: thanks sir, i dont have any idea for this. The main problem is my laravel inertia vue project not working on production shared hosting, its still return 419 error :')

Answer (score 2):

In your `Middleware/HandleInertiaRequests.php` file add the csrf token globally.

```
/**
 * Defines the props that are shared by default.
 *
 * @see https://inertiajs.com/shared-data
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function share(Request $request): array
{
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
          'csrf_token' => csrf_token(),
    ]);
}
```

Within your form add the instance.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="this.$page.props.csrf_token">
```

Finally, make a call, in the below example I am using the Inertia useForm() function to log a user in.

```
<script setup>
  import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

  const form = useForm({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    _token: String,
    processing: false,
  });

  let submit = () => {
    form.processing = true
    
    form.post('/login')
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This one should be marked as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Now add csrf variable inside script at the blade file, like this.

```
<script>
     export default {
        data: () => ({
            csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
          }),        
    }
</script>
```

You will see a meta tag in your blade.php file like this.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: I have try that, and not working

Comment: try new solution.

Comment: same bro, its still not working

Comment: This solution will not work since the blade template csrf token will be out of date after the first inertia request. The correct answer is this one -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/75886022/3333549

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:

Laravel automatically includes the proper CSRF token when making requests via Inertia or Axios. However, if you're using Laravel, be sure to omit the csrf-token meta tag from your project, as this will prevent the CSRF token from refreshing properly.

From this I think you don't really have to do anything?